# video and mp3 download

Tags: video, download, converters

I am editing videos for my YouTube channel by downloading and converting videos in MP3 and MP4 formats. I can't find a good website for downloading. Either the download is very slow, the website is overwhelmed with ads, or there are errors during downloading – sometimes it doesn't work at all. Especially downloading copyrighted videos is very difficult. I want to download videos not only from YouTube but also from other platforms, and I don't want to deal with this separately. Even though I use a download manager, it doesn't download all the videos and errors occur. Do you know of one or more reliable websites that fulfill all these requirements? Thank you in advance!

download and mp3 converter